# Selenium sendKeys only append files for input[type=file multiple]

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenide, react-dropzone

I am unable to clear hidden multiple file input using selenium.

HTML source

```html
<input type="file" multiple style="display: none"/>
```

Selenium

```java
webElement.sendKeys(file1.absolutePath); //  file1 added
webElement.sendKeys(file2.absolutePath); // ⚠ appends file2
webElement.sendKeys(file3.absolutePath); // ⚠ appends file3
/// and so on
```

Files just continuously appending into the input and there is no obvious way to clear it. I've shown the input element for debugging purposes and all files had been put in the field.

[image: Files just appended to input]

I've tried to use `WebElement.clear()`, `sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE)` and several others. No one does work with the hidden input element.

Comment: you could use execute_script to remove the value attribute.  Or set value to "".  Why did you want to clear?

Comment: React-dropzone handles file immediately when it added into field. sendKeys just append new fiels into list, so 1st file uploaded, then 1sn and 2nd uploaded, then 1st, 2nd and 3rd, etc. and i have list of uploads like "1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3" that's not what I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply grab the tag and use **`driver.execute`** to change the value of that tag.

```
js = "document.getElement(By.tagName("input")).value = "+file2.absolutePath; 
driver.execute_script(js).
```